# The loop breaks after one cycle

Tags: python, while-loop

The question is to check the guess entered as the input to the random number generator,

Here is my code for that,

```
import random

int1 = 1
int2 = 50

correctNumber = random.randint(1, 50)

a =int(input("Please enter your number: "))

while True:
    if a > correctNumber:
        print("LOW")
        a = int(input("Please enter again : "))

    elif a < correctNumber:
        print("HIGH")
        a = int(input("Please enter again : "))

    elif a == correctNumber:
        print("YOU GOT IT RIGHT")

    break
```

The loop breaks after one cycle,

Comment: Remove the `print` in `a = print(...)`.

Comment: There is exactly one value of `NoneType`, and that is `None`, and it's the value returned by `print()`.

Comment: `a = int(input("Please enter your number: ")); print(a)`

Comment: ***The loop breaks after one cycle,*** Because you have used break! Keep break inside `elif` to break only if correct answer is passes.

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem:

```
import random

int1 = 1
int2 = 50

correctNumber = random.randint(1, 50)

a =int(input("Please enter your number: "))

while True:
    if a > correctNumber:
        print("LOW")
        a = int(input("Please enter again : "))

    elif a < correctNumber:
        print("HIGH")
        a = int(input("Please enter again : "))

    elif a == correctNumber:
        print("YOU GOT IT RIGHT")
        break #break used inside elif to loop while correct is not provided
```

Answer (score 1):

Your booleans seem backward to me. When `if a > correctNumber:` the the guess is `"HIGH"` not `"LOW"`.

With that, instead of `break`ing. You could make your `while` loop condition based on whether the guess is correct.

```
import random

int1 = 1
int2 = 50

correctNumber = random.randint(int1, int2)

a = int(input("Please enter your number: "))

while  a != correctNumber:
    if a < correctNumber:
        print("LOW")

    elif a > correctNumber:
        print("HIGH")

    a = int(input("Please enter again : "))

print("YOU GOT IT RIGHT")
```

If you are using a recent version of python, you can simplify it even further by assigning in the `while` loop with the `:=` (walrus) operator:

```
import random

int1 = 1
int2 = 50

correctNumber = random.randint(int1, int2)

while (a := int(input("Please enter your number: "))) != correctNumber:
    print("LOW" if a < correctNumber else "HIGH")
        

print("YOU GOT IT RIGHT")
```

Comment: `"LOW"` might be displayed to inform the user to guess a number lower than your current guess.

Comment: That's fair @Bibhav — I guess we would need to do some user testing to see how people interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

Indent the break statement from the final line.

The break keyword is used to break out of the while loop. At its current state, the loop is terminating after 1 cycle because it hits the break keyword.

If you indent the break statement, it will be part of the elif block of code, and will only execute after a == correctNumber.

This code would work:

```py
import random

correctNumber = random.randint(1, 50)

a =int(input("Please enter your number: "))

while True:
    if a > correctNumber:
        print("LOW")
        a = int(input("Please enter again : "))

    elif a < correctNumber:
        print("HIGH")
        a = int(input("Please enter again : "))

    elif a == correctNumber:
        print("YOU GOT IT RIGHT")
        break
```

Learn more about break [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_break.asp)